# Making branches closer in a tree

Tags: forest

Suppose that I have the following tree... and I want to make only the second and third branches closer. Is that possible?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
       dot/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[ ,name=a,for tree={s sep=50pt,l sep=5cm,dot,grow=1}, 
  [ ,name=b,edge   ]
  [ ,name=e,   ]
  [ ,name=f,  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to use the `y` key:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{forest}

\tikzset{
  dot/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
}

\begin{document}
Without change:
\begin{forest}
baseline
[ ,name=a,for tree={s sep=50pt,l sep=5cm,dot,grow=1}, 
  [ ,name=b,edge   ]
  [ ,name=e,   ]
  [ ,name=f  ]
]
\end{forest}\par\bigskip

Applying the change:
\begin{forest}
baseline
[ ,name=a,for tree={s sep=50pt,l sep=5cm,dot,grow=1}, 
  [ ,name=b,edge   ]
  [ ,name=e,   ]
  [ ,before drawing tree={y-=15mm},name=f  ]
]
\end{forest}\par\bigskip

Applying the change:
\begin{forest}
baseline
[ ,name=a,for tree={s sep=50pt,l sep=5cm,dot,grow=1}, 
  [ ,name=b,edge   ]
  [ ,before drawing tree={y-=15mm},name=e,   ]
  [ ,name=f  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As **Sašo Živanović** mentions in [`his comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252084/making-branches-closer-in-a-tree/252087?noredirect=1#comment601367_252087), a more generic solution, as it works in a tree of any orientation, would be to use the `s` key:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{forest}

\tikzset{
  dot/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
}

\begin{document}
Without change:
\begin{forest}
baseline
[ ,name=a,for tree={s sep=50pt,l sep=5cm,dot,grow=1}, 
  [ ,name=b,edge   ]
  [ ,name=e,   ]
  [ ,name=f  ]
]
\end{forest}\par\bigskip

Applying the change:
\begin{forest}
baseline
[ ,name=a,for tree={s sep=50pt,l sep=5cm,dot,grow=1}, 
  [ ,name=b,edge   ]
  [ ,name=e,   ]
  [ ,before packing={s+=15mm},name=f  ]
]
\end{forest}\par\bigskip

Applying the change:
\begin{forest}
baseline
[ ,name=a,for tree={s sep=50pt,l sep=5cm,dot,grow=1}, 
  [ ,name=b,edge   ]
  [ ,before packing={s+=15mm},name=e,   ]
  [ ,name=f  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another option (maybe even a bit more generic, as it works in a tree of any orientation), is to use key `s`, like `before packing={s+=15mm}`

Comment: @SašoŽivanović You're right. I've added your suggestion to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović By the way, I remember that some time ago I and user cfr volunteered to test a new beta version of `forest`. How is the new version project going? Do you still need testing volunteers?

Comment: And I'm much grateful for the offer and will take it ... as soon as I have the *time* to finish the new version. Argh, time!

Comment: @SašoŽivanović It's a pleasure for me; I love forest. Of course, I understand that time is a scarce resource.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to half the specified sibling separation but use a `phantom` node to increase the separation of the other branches.

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{
       dot/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1.5,fill=black},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[ ,name=a,for tree={s sep=25pt,l sep=5cm,dot,grow=1},
  [ ,name=b,edge   ]
  [,phantom]
  [ ,name=e,   ]
  [ ,name=f,  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Before:

[image: standard]

After:

[image: phantom separation]